# Why can't functions be assigned to variables and keep their functionality?

Tags: javascript, jquery

This works:

```
var foo = $("#bar");
foo.html("Hello.");
```

This doesn't:

```
var foo = $("#bar").html;
foo("Hello.");
```

What breaks the functionality?

Comment: I guess the second call will run in `window` scope

Comment: Probably because calling [`.html(htmlString)`](http://api.jquery.com/html/#html2) and passing a value returns [`jQuery`](http://api.jquery.com/html/) (an instance of the jQuery object) as denoted in the docs. If you're saving the function reference, it may lose the object reference. Just a guess.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well this should:

```
var bar = $("#bar");
var foo = bar.html.bind(bar);
foo("Hello.");
```

In your second example, the html function lost its calling context when you assigned it to the foo variable.

Comment: Or just change `foo("Hello.");` to `foo.call( $("#bar"), "Hello.")`

Answer (score 4):

jQuery references `this` when you call their functions. We can make your example work if we set `this` with something like `bind`.

https://jsfiddle.net/ripter/6hbqtn5j/

```js
// Normal case
//$('#bar').html('<h1>Hello World</h1>');

// save the html function for later
// jQuery relies on 'this', so we have to make sure we keep that reference.
var barHtml = $('#bar').html.bind($('#bar'));
barHtml('<h1>Hello from function reference</h1>');
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="bar">

</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

The reason the reference of `html()` does not work in your example is because the scope of `this` has changed within the function when you call it.

In the normal example (ie. `$('#bar').html('Hello.')`), `this` refers to the DOMElements held within the jQuery object.

In the function reference version `this` has changed to point to the `window`. To fix this you need to call the `html()` method reference providing the scope of `this`, using `call()`.

As you can see from the example below, this isn't very helpful as you then need to call the DOM twice to retrieve the `#bar` element.

```js
var foo = $("#bar").html;
foo.call($("#bar"), "Hello.");
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="bar"></div>
```

`bind()` would also achieve the same result, and have the exact same drawback.

Answer (score -2):

When you call the html method, you need to pass the args in at that time. Simply put, it just doesn't work that way. if you did a

```
    var myHtml = 'hello world';
    var foo = $('#bar').html(myHtml);
```

you'd find it works. when calling a method, the arguments should be associated with it...
you're essentially assigning a property 'html' to the Jquery object and it's overwriting the method.
I'm pretty sure...

Comment: The OP is asking why he can't store a *reference* to the `html()` method in a variable - which is a perfectly valid thing to want to do.